# power series computation

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{k^3}{3^k}z^k$. Compute the
>   following:
>
> a. $f^{(6)}(0)$
>
> b. $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^4}dz$

I dont understand how to do these problems, the answer in the book is:

a. $f^{(6)}(0)=6!a_6=\frac{6!6^3}{3^6}$

b. $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^4}d=\frac{2\pi i}{3!}f^{(3)}(0)=\frac{2\pi i(3!a_3)}{3!}=2\pi iz$

Comment: So the radius of convergence is $>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a., the expression you have for $f(z)$ is a sum of terms $a_iz^i$  The sixth derivative of each term, when evaluated at $z=0$ is $0$ except for the sixth.  All the lower ones become a constant and then have a derivative taken, while all the higher ones still have a factor of $z^{i-6}$ which is zero.  So the sixth derivative evaluated at zero is $6!a_6$ as claimed.

For b. look up the [Cauchy integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_integral_formula).  The curve is a closed circle, so you need the term in $f$ of order $z^3$ so when you divide by $z^4$ you are left with $z^{-1}$ as the integral formula requires.

Comment: I seem to understand b now, thanks for that. but a im still confused, can you elaborate a bit more please?

Answer (score 1):

a. $f(z)$ is also $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {f^{(k)}(0) \over k!}z^k$, and the Taylor expansion is unique. What do you conclude?

b. This follows from the [Residue Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)

Comment: How did you know $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {f^{(k)}(0) \over k!}z^k$ is the Taylor expansion?